# Use traefik middleware globally

Tags: docker, traefik

i am trying to declare https redirect inside the `traefik.yml` file. For now i tried to add those rules inside the **traefik** service in `docker-compose.yml`. That worked like a charm. Although i'd prefer to configure this global and middleware redirect inside the `traefik.yml` file and then just reference it in the traefik service on `docker-compose.yml`.

### What i had before

```sh
version: '3'

networks:
  web:
    external: true

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.1
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./.traefik/traefik.yml:/traefik.yml
      - ./.traefik/acme.json:/acme.json
    networks:
      - web
    labels:
       - "traefik.enable=true"
       - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule=Host(`$HOSTNAME`)"
       - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.service=api@internal"
       - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.tls.certresolver=le"
       - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.entrypoints=https"
       # Global redirect to https
       - "traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.rule=hostregexp(`{host:.+}`)"
       - "traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.entrypoints=http"
       - "traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.middlewares=redirect-to-https"
       # Middleware redirect
       - "traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-to-https.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
```

That worked easily and redirected all other domains from http to https.

### What i want now

I want to declare those redirects inside the `traefik.yml`.

So far i have done this.

```
api: {}

entryPoints:
  http:
    address: ":80"
  https:
    address: ":443"

log:
  level: DEBUG

providers:
  docker:
    endpoint: "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
    exposedByDefault: false
    network: web

http:
  # Global redirect to https
  routers:
    http-catchall:
      rule: hostregexp(`{host:.+}`)"
      entrypoints:
        http
      middlewares:
        - redirect-to-https
  # Middleware redirect
  middlewares:
    redirect-to-https:
      redirectScheme:
        scheme: https

certificatesResolvers:
  le:
    acme:
      email: john@doe.com
      storage: acme.json
      # Activate for Development: Certificate will not be valid. It's only for testing if it can be obtained.
      #caServer: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
      httpChallenge:
        entryPoint: http
```

As you can see i declared the http settings.

My question is now how can i reference those settings into my traefik service?

I tried it with

`- "traefik.http.middlewares=redirect-to-https"`

`- "traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-to-https"`

`- "traefik.http.middlewares.traefik=redirect-to-https@file"`

None of them work. Some show the middleware in the dashboard but it is not linked to any settings.

Did anyone find a solution to this? I can't get out anything from the docs about this. I think it must be linked somehow to the **@file**.

Thank you

Comment: @jujule i did no further invest it actually. We just declare it in the docker-compose.yml files of each project

Answer (score 11):

`@file` means that the middleware was defined in the file provider.

You can add a file provider like this in traefik.yml.

```
providers:
  file:
    directory: "/path/to/dynamic/conf"
```

Create a file in that directory with the middleware.

```
http:
  middlewares:
    redirect-to-https:
      redirectScheme:
        scheme: https
```

You can now reference redirect-to-https@file in your labels.

```
- "traefik.http.middlewares.traefik=redirect-to-https@file"
```

**NOTE**: Some of your configuration in traefik.yml might need to be moved to your new yml file. I am new to Traefik and have not full knownlegde of why yet.

See the following sections in documentation:

- https://docs.traefik.io/middlewares/overview/#provider-namespace
- https://docs.traefik.io/providers/file/

Answer (score 6):

In fact, you don't need to set this middleware to traefik in labels block. If you have such configuration in your `traefik.yml`:

```
http:
  routers:
    http-catchall:
      rule: hostregexp(`{host:.+}`)
      entrypoints:
        - http
      middlewares:
        - redirect-to-https

  middlewares:
    redirect-to-https:
      redirectScheme:
        scheme: https
        permanent: false
```

It means - all traffic which came to entrypoint `http` should use middleware `redirect-to-https` and be redirected to another entrypoint: `https`. This configuration is globally.

So, you just have to set your container to `https` entrypoint (as you did, in your example)

```
labels:
  - "traefik.enable=true"
  - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.entrypoints=https"
  - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule=Host(`traefik.mydomain.ua`)"
  - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.tls=true"
  - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.tls.certresolver=letsEncrypt"
  - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.service=api@internal"
```

Comment: why do you need a router route if there is already a catch one?

Comment: @Danielo515 I believe it's because there is a rule to ensure that the host matches a specific pattern. So as long as the rule passes then http-catchall will be used.

Comment: Please note that this configuration `http: ` should be in Dynamic configuration file (NOT `/etc/traefik/traefik.yml`. Maybe your configuration is different and traefik.yml is really your dynamic configuration, idk, but you should not mix these two.