# Traefik2 define rule for all services

Tags: docker, traefik

I am using Traefik v2 and I would like to write a rule to apply headers if the Client IP is a specific one. This rule must apply to all proxied services and I wonder if I can define this rule only once in the yaml file.

The rule should be something like:

```yaml
http:
  routers:
    from-legacy-client:
      entryPoints:
        - web
      rule: ClientIP(`192.168.1.1`)
      middlewares:
        - legacy-headers

middlewares:
    legacy-headers:
      headers:
        customRequestHeaders:
          X-dco-role: "DCO"
```

Iknow it currently does not work because I have not defined the destination `service`. Is it possible to "wildcard" the involved services meaning "all services"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use traefik middleware globally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59929838/use-traefik-middleware-globally)

Comment: Unforntunately I don't think so. I know I can define middlewares in file and reference them in docker labels with `@file` but this does not prevent from assigning the middleware in all docker services' labels.